# How to concatenate data in two columns and make it as another column access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table and i want to concatenate NAME and EID fields. How do i specify that in SQL query.

```
     Name     Description       EID  

     name1      ssdad          1001
     name2      gfd            1002
     name3      gfdsffsdf      1003
```

I wanted it like

```
     Name     Description       EID     Name_EID

     name1      ssdad          1001     name1_1001
     name2      gfd            1002     name2_1002
     name3      gfdsffsdf      1003     name3_1003
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this in the table definition, use a [`Calculated Field`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-HA101820564.aspx). If you want it in a query, then use:

```
SELECT
    MyTable.Name & "_" & MyTable.EID
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Please do not use + in MS Access, if a field is null you will get unexpected results. The concatenator is &

Comment: It is not working in VBA. i can not see what the error is, because it is not printing in Debug.Print

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Name, description, EID, Name & "_" & EID FROM TABLE
```